# Dynamic carousel in PHP Laravel only shows one image

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a dynamic carousel in laravel but I see only one image. I have looked for solutions for hours but I'm stuck

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item">
@foreach($sliders as $slider)
    <img src="{{url('images', $slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-    100" alt="...">
</div>
@endforeach
```

This is my blade code

```
@extends('front.master')

@section('content')

<main role="main">

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
@foreach($sliders as $slider)
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{url('images', $slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-  100" alt="...">
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
</div>

<section class="jumbotron text-center">
</section>

<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
<div class="container">


</div>

</main>

@endsection
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes I'm using bootstrap carousel @AdityaThakur

Comment: I can see what might be the issue, check my answer.

Comment: I did make a change you suggested on your answer and now no image is showing.

Comment: can you share your blade code, and also check developer console for any js errors.

Comment: i updated the code on the question, on the console i can see all images but they are not showing.

Comment: what is your bootstrap version? and where have you placed your jquery files?

Comment: bootstrap 4.0.0 and jquery files are in a file master.blade.php

Comment: It has something to do with jquery not running, the carousel is not being initialised inside the bootstrap.js, make sure the files are placed in order and just before the closing tag `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tag of your `<div class="carousel-item">` is inside the loop, while the starting tag is not. You need to loop with `<div class="carousel-item">` instead of just image.

change this

```
<div class="carousel-item">
@foreach($sliders as $slider)
    <img src="{{url('images', $slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-    100" alt="...">
</div>
@endforeach
```

to this

```
@foreach($sliders as $slider)
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="{{url('images', $slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: share your answer if you got a solution to this